# Publish Django project with gunicorn and NGINX

Tags: python, django, sockets, nginx, gunicorn

Im trying to publish my Django project with NGINX and gunicorn, but I get permission denied from gunicorn.

My last steps what I did.

```
mkdir /home/sama/websites
cd /home/sama/websites
mkdir test_project
cd test_project
```

create Virtualenvirement for this project
`virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.8 venv`

Virtualenvirement activate
`source venv/bin/activate`

Gunicorn & Django install

```
pip3 install gunicorn
pip3 install django
```

create project

```
cd ..
django-admin startproject config test_project
```

allow firewall to port 8000
`sudo ufw allow 8000`

run first test
`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

open my server ip on webbrowser
myIP:8000
I can see Django basic page

stop server
CTRL + C

testGunicorn 
`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 config.wsgi`

testagain on webbrowser
Again I can see Djangos page

Server stop
CTRL + C

exit virtualenvirement
`deactivate`

config Gunicorn 
create 2 files in
/etc/systemd/system/

gunicorn.socket and gunicorn.service

edit this files
`sudo nano  /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn_test_project.socket`

```
/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

```
/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sama
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sama/websites/test_project
ExecStart=/home/sama/websites/test_project/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock config.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

test socket

```
sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket
```

systemlink created, check it
`file /run/gunicorn.sock`
Output: /run/gunicorn.sock: socket

`curl --unix-socket /run/gunicorn.sock localhost`

And now I get **permission denied**

I already set permission for the folder test_project to user sama and group www-data, but without any effects. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I see no good reason to use systemd socket activation here.

Just use a service file and have Gunicorn bind to HTTP.

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sama
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sama/websites/test_project
ExecStart=/home/sama/websites/test_project/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 config.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. But I have a second question.   This is my NGINX file     ```listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my_secret_domainname;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/sama/websites/test_project;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
} ``` But I cant reach the domain via browser, but when I type subdomain I can reach. I didnt have any subdomains configured

Comment: That's a different question; please ask it as such.